# how to limit the range of numbers in angular2 for an input text?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have an input text field. `<input type="text" [ngModel]="textvalue | currencyinrhello" (ngModelChange)="onTextChange($event)" (keypress)="restrictNumeric($event)" />`

i want to restrict the value of the input from 15,000 to 5,00,000. I don't want the user to input a number above it.

Comment: any reason for using keypress event?

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 native. You don't need any angular 2 code here. Only for form validation. If user types in some number which is not inside the range, or any invalid character, the form will be invalid.

`<input type="number" name="quantity" min="15000" max="5000000">`

Answer (score 1):

In angular2 way, you can use directives.

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[restrict]',
})
export class InputRestricter{


@Input('restrict_minvalue') minValue: number;
constructor(private el: ElementRef,private renderer: Renderer) {

}    
@HostListener('keyup',['$event']) onKeyUp(event){   
    if(this.minValue){
        let el = <HTMLSelectElement> event.target;
        if ($(el).val() <= this.minValue) {
            el.setCustomValidity('Value is invalid');
        } else {
            el.setCustomValidity('');
        }
    }
}
```

and then use the directive in your template

```
<input restrict  [restrict_minvalue]="15000"/>
```

The directive will make your input invalid, if the input value is less than 15000. You can implement max value ability in same way.

Comment: I want the data to automatically change to 500000 even if you try to put a number above it, on runtime. sorry for not completing the question.

Comment: @VishalNair Then you can simply set the value $(el).val("15000") instead of setting it invalid. In the directive you  have the input element, you can manage it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, i have used keyup event

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    template: `
    <label>Enter the Amount:</label>
   <input type="text" #textbox [(ngModel)]="textvalue"  (keyup)="restrictNumeric($event, textbox.value, 15000, 500000)" />
    `
})
export class App {
  string: textvalue;
  restrictNumeric(event, value, min, max) 
  {
    if(parseInt(value) < min || isNaN(parseInt(value))) 
        console.log("invalid min value");
    else if(parseInt(value) > max || isNaN(parseInt(value)) 
        this.textvalue = 500000;
  }
}
```